# target="_blank" does not open a new tab

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drupal

```
$description = $this->t('A user-defined date format. See the <a href="http://php.net/manual/function.date.php" target="_blank">PHP </a> for available options.');
```

This code does not open the link in a new tab, instead it opens on the same tab. is there a way I can fix this code? Or is there an alternate to `target="_blank"` or to open a URL in a new tab?

Comment: I believe that this can still be overriden by the user's local setting (especially in Chrome)...and, frankly, that should be the case. Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery :

add an ID to the ancher (here is id="myAnchor") :

```
$(document).on('click', 'a#myAnchor', function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
    window.open(url, '_blank');
});
```

Comment: This again opens the URL in the same tab.

Comment: This should work, check if there is another code to overwrite it. Also have you tried different browsers, maybe the settings or plugins on your browser doesn't allow pages to open new tab.

Answer (score 0):

use this for new tab in js

```
    <script> 
    window.open('http://testsite.com, "_blank");
    </script>
or
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="webMnu" onclick="window.open('http://testsite.com','plain');">Enroll</a>
```

Comment: please allow popup when open new tab.browser off open popup need allow then open next tab

Answer (score 0):

Check your page source. If in source you can also see `target="_blank"` then it means that action is overridden with JavaScript so you should fix JS.